# iOS binary submission and encryption + KeychainItemWrapper

Tags: ios, encryption, appstore-approval

I am trying to upload an app to iTunesConnect and it is asking the following yes/no question:

> "Have you added or made changes to encryption features since your last
>   submission of this app?"

I have used the `KeychainItemWrapper` class and `Security framework` in my app.
How should I answer the above question?

Comment: If you do not know that either you have made encryption or not in your app! then for sure you have not added any encryption in your code :) . So You can set it No :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have encrypted any content in your app then you should say **Yes** there, otherwise **No**. As per my observations KeychainItemWrapper is used when data is encrypted, so you should Say **Yes** in that case.